# How can I pause and resume video recording if the stock app does not support this feature?

Tags: sony-xperia-mini-pro, video-recording

I have an Xperia Mini Pro with Android 2.3 (and upgradeable to Android 4). Its recording program does not have ability to pause and resume recording.

**How can I pause and resume video recording if the stock app does not support this feature?**

Comment: Just FYI: My colleague has this phone who had recently upgraded to 4.0.? and says still he can't pause/resume the video.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Answering the Question

I've been searching for a solution to this issue since I've seen your question, probably when you've set a bounty. Till now I've found tons of unhappy users complaining about the same issue, no pause/resume during a video record.

I've read just about every first fifty results presented for every search that I came up with on Google, been into Google Market, reference forums, etc... *sigh!*

The only answer that I've found relevant to be mentioned was provided by [Ryan Conrad](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/10670/16265) concerning this topic, for the same phone. <sup>(no need for transcription to this answer)</sup>

Since this is being requested a few years (at least since 2011 that users are complaining at [Google Forums](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18797)), and since the functionality to pause while recording needs system support due to the API and hardware being used that must provide such capabilities, software developers cannot go around this.

Some devices may be capable of dealing with  the pause/resume feature, but that's unclear. I believe that you'll just have to wait until manufacturers and developers can't stand the voice of the unhappy user anymore, and improve this issue.

---

## The Android API currently does not provide the pause method

<sup>This is a bit technical, but was solicited on the comments.</sup>

The [public class MediaRecorder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html), being used since API level 1, doesn't has the capability to pause, as one can observe from the MediaRecorder State Diagram:

[image: MediaRecorder State Diagram]

When recording, the API allows us to either use the `reset()` or `stop()` Public Methods:

> `reset()` -> Restarts the MediaRecorder to its idle state.
>
> `stop()` -> Stops recording.

Comment: Thanks, can you exactly say me that what is source of the issue? Android API, SonyEricsson, or just this model? Please give me an official source that say expresses the issue officially. Currently with android-based phones are capable to pause/resume video recording?

Comment: @Reza I've edited the answer as per your request. A bit technical, but directs the blame to the Android API.

Comment: I really do not think you should be blaming the API within Android for the lack of that feature as the camera hardware is unique and dependent on hardware, not all handsets would share the same camera hardware chipset! If they did, then the pause/resume would be in place and be a de-facto standard.

Comment: @t0mm13b You've raised a valid point, title is rephrased to remove any blame from Android.

Comment: @Zuul ahh okie :) No worries there ;)